# If Siva has five faces, then why do his statues only have one?

Tags: shiva, puranas, shaivism

Does Siva have five faces (Panchanana)? Is there any scriptural reference?

If he has five faces, then why do the statues (Murtis) of Siva have only one face? What happened to the other four faces?

Comment: It's easier to carve. That's also why the figures are not to scale.

Comment: Sadashiva form has 5 faces, other forms like Rudra Avatar, Nataraja, Dakshinamurty, etc.. have one face (though they can manifest 5 faces also in various circumstances)...